# Export selected objects to a json text file

Tags: python

I've written the code below to dump location data of selected objects, 
Hhowever its not ideal.
I'm not deeply into python's json library
What i would like to generat is a file that looks alike

```
{
  { "name" : camera
       { "x" : 0.404404,
         "y" : 0.001111,
         "z" : 0.00202  }
   },
  { "name" : target
       { "x":   12.111111,
         "y":    6.00020

etc...
```

Currently each  object and its positions are inside a signle { }, block.
So the x,y,z data is not subnested, i'm not sure how to do it.

Here is the code i wrote:

```
# import the necessary modules we need
import bpy, os, json

# get the current selection
selection = bpy.context.selected_objects

# get path of the blend file (file should have been saved at least once)
tempFolder = bpy.path.abspath("//")

# make a filename
filename = os.path.join (tempFolder, ".Locations.json")
# open a file to write to
file = open(filename, "w")   # a is for appending  w writes new

# initialize
result = "{\n"
resultJson = ""

# loop through selected objects
for sel in selection:
     # get the current object's dimensions
     loc = sel.location
     # store it in json
     resultJson = { "name" : sel.name , "x":loc.x, "y":loc.y, "z":loc.z   }
     # turns a single jsonline in a string and adds ',' for next object
     result+= json.dumps(resultJson,indent=4) + ','

result = result[:-1] # remove last comma from joined string objects
result = result +'\n}'
file.write(result)
file.close()
```

Comment: Since you are able to access all the properties, this question is off-topic IMO. It's more like a basic python question so I'd suggest: Ask how to format your json string on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)....

Comment: Well i was in doubt a bit about it, it turned out people regularly popup questions about import export to some format from Blender (in this case json), if it gets solved here, Blender users can find an answer from here. To ask something python related is Ok i think as an artist i'm not in depth with those subjects while some here are.